# How to automatically show the diacrtics on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a text that includes `ă,ș` etc. Is there any way to show the diacritics instead of `"?"` on a web page, without using the HTML character codes for each of them?

Comment: What you have tried till now ?

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the right encoding:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    ...
</head>
```